# App keeps launching to a blank screen Test Flight React Native expo

Tags: ios, react-native, testflight

App is working fine in Android Device after production
and its working fine on ios expo. but when i create .ipa file for production and test app via testflight its stuck on white screen.
so app store is keep showing me this reult.

I am Attaching my App.js  code

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import { Button, Text,BackHandler, View,TouchableOpacity,StyleSheet,Image,ActivityIndicator,StatusBar,AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

import Navigations from './Navigations'

const Stack = createStackNavigator();


function App() {


   useEffect(() => {
    function prepare() {
    
        SplashScreen.hideAsync();
        // Pre-load fonts, make any API calls you need to do here
      
    }

    prepare();
  }, []);



  return (

  
    <NavigationContainer>
    
    <Navigations>
      
    </Navigations>
   
    </NavigationContainer>

 
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now my package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.5.2",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "@redmin_delishaj/react-native-select": "^1.0.6",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.2.2",
    "@unimodules/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@unimodules/react-native-adapter": "~6.5.0",
    "expo": "^43.0.0",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "^4.0.3",
    "expo-av": "^10.1.2",
    "expo-document-picker": "^10.0.3",
    "expo-facebook": "^12.0.3",
    "expo-google-app-auth": "~9.0.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "^11.0.3",
    "expo-permissions": "^13.0.3",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.13.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.1.0",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "npm": "^8.1.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-credit-card-input": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-customizable-checkbox": "^1.0.14",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.2.3",
    "react-native-image-overlay": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.12",
    "react-native-image-slider-box": "^1.1.9",
    "react-native-image-viewing": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.4",
    "react-native-material-menu": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.2",
    "react-native-pull-to-refresh": "^2.1.3",
    "react-native-ratings": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.0",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-swiper-flatlist": "^3.0.15",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-video-controls": "^2.8.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-native-webview": "11.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

and i am posting reply from App store

Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

We continue to run into the same bug in your app. Specifically, your app keeps launching to a blank screen and no further content loads. Please review the details below and complete the next steps.

Review device details:

- Device type: iPhone and iPad
- OS version: iOS 15.1

Next Steps

Please run your app on a device to reproduce the issues, then revise and submit your app for review. If at first you're unable to reproduce the issue, try the following:

- For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce.
- For app updates, install the new version as an update to the previous version, then follow the steps to reproduce.

If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to this message in Resolution Center to provide information on how these features were intended to work.

[Actual Screen shot from ios Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voA0b.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am having this issue too but I believe one of my changes fixed and then introduced it. Check out your `“main”:`  and “metro.config.js” if you have one, expo is picky in their structured workflows.

Might also be missing linked react native packages, react-native-svg makes me want to never use svgs in expo